# Managing char * in real life

Tags: c++

I have function that is called with parameter `char* descriptor`. In function I need to check descriptor not equals empty string `""`. If it is so, give `descriptor` name `"new_name"`. But name should not be constant since it will be changed in function `encode`. This is code how I realize it:

```
f1(char* descriptor)
{
    if (strcmp(descriptor, "") == 0) 
        {
        char d[9] ="new_name";
        descriptor = d;
        }
...
encode(descriptor)
}

void encode(char* descriptor)
{
...
}
```

Is this code correct?
For my point of view code looks clumsy. Is it possible to code such task more elegant way and make it more simple?

Comment: Why not using `std::string` ?

Comment: First comment: `char d[9] ="new_name"; descriptor = d;` doesn't work *at all* because you're setting your char* to a piece of memory that immediately goes out of scope.  That will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: using a `std::string`, considering that you tagged the post with `c++` and not `c`? and

Comment: please send your exact code and not pseudo-code since, you know exactly what is going on on your program, while others don't

Comment: What do you mean in your title with "real life"? xD
You mean in a realistic production environment? "Real life" here is confusing :P

Comment: I find this question - as it is now - awful: 1. Your code doesn't compile for several reasons. 2. Using `std::string` should be obvious. Why `char*`? 3. The question title is confusing. So this question shows too little research effort, it is unclear, and it is not useful. Rant end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using C++, you should be using `std::string` or some variant. I'll assume you're using C, since your code is pure C.

```
if (strcmp(descriptor, "") == 0) 
{
    char d[9] ="new_name";
    descriptor = d;
}
```

This is wrong (and, believe me, very bad) because `d` becomes out of scope as soon as it gets out of scope, i.e as soon as that `if` block ends. So, there, you have an undefined behavior. If you had defined `d` at the top-level of your function, though, that would be okay.

```
f1(char* descriptor)
{
    char d[9] ="new_name";
    if (strcmp(descriptor, "") == 0) 
    {
        descriptor = d;
    }
    ...
    encode(descriptor)
}
```

Now you're okay, because you're not referring to `d` once it's out of scope : since its scope is the whole function (and not just an `if` block), when you call `encore(descriptor)`, it does still exist.

Comment: @MatthewGunn no, because once you leave the function, the fact that `descriptor` was assigned `d` is discarded. We are not modifying `*descriptor` here, only `descriptor`, so this is a local affectation that does not "propagate" to the function calling `f1`.

Comment: I think it's better a `strcpy` because we don't know if inside encode the pointer is preserved or changed. If preserved it goes out of scope anyway when program leaves `f1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
f1(std::string& descriptor)
{
    if (descriptor.empty()) 
    {
        encode(descriptor)
    }
}

void encode(std::string& descriptor)
{
    // Change string here.
}
```

Consider that I use `std::string` because you tagged the post with `c++` and not `c` and I don't see any reason to use `char*` instead of a `std::string` in this case.

#### EDIT

My code encode string only when empty. If you want to change the string anyway you must modify the code:

```
f1(std::string& descriptor)
{
    if (descriptor.empty()) 
    {
        descriptor = "new_name";
    }
    encode(descriptor);
}

void encode(std::string& descriptor)
{
    // Change string here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
f1(char* descriptor)
{
    if (strcmp(descriptor, "") == 0) 
    {
        strcpy(descriptor, "new_name");
    }
...
encode(descriptor)
}
```

Comment: I'd simply do `if (descriptor != nullptr && descriptor[0] == '\0')` instead of `strcmp`.

Comment: What if the memory that `descriptor` points to isn't enough for `new_name`?

Comment: if was not enough, allocation code would be there. but there isn't so i suppose that it already has enough space

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume:

1. `char* descriptor` points to a buffer of sufficient length:
2. Overwriting descriptor's buffer is entirely fine.

Then you can do the single line:

```
encode(*descriptor:descriptor?strcpy(descriptor,"new_name"));
```

The ternary operator evaluates to `descriptor` if `*descriptor` is not null, and the result of `strcpy(descriptor,'new_name')` otherwise, and `strcpy` returns the destination string, which is `descriptor`, newly overwritten with "new_name".

Comment: But what if descriptor has not enough space for "new_name"?

Comment: Then you cannot do this.